# Bias for kernel density estimator (periodic case)

Tags: kernel-smoothing

Kernel density estimator is given by 
$$\hat{f}(x,h)=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^{n}K(\frac{x-X_{i}}{h})$$ 
where $X_1,...X_n$  i.i.d with some unknown density $f$, $h$ - bandwith,

$K$ - kernel function    (
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x)dx=1$,
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x)xdx=0$,
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x)x^2dx<\infty$).
The bias  can be computed using Taylor expansion:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{h}K(\frac{x-y}{h})f(y)dy-f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(y)\left(f(x-hy)-f(x)\right)dy$$ $$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(y)\left(f'(x)hy+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)(hy)^{2}+o(h^{2})\right)dy=\frac{1}{2}f''(x)h^{2}+o(h^{2})$$

How to deal with periodic   kernel and $f$ ($\int_{0}^{1}K(x)dx=1$,$\int_{0}^{1}K(x)xdx=0$,$\int_{0}^{1}K(x)x^2dx<\infty$)?

How can I use taylor expansion?($\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{h}K(\frac{y-x}{h})f(y)dy=\int_{-\frac{x}{h}}^{1-\frac{x}{h}}K(y)f(x-yh)dy\neq\int_{0}^{1}K(y)f(x-yh)dy$ -I can't use kernel properties)

Could you recommend a good book about  kernel smoothing for circular data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google brings up this, which indicates that when working with circular data you'll need a different definition of 'bias' for a start:

> However, when using data on the circle, we cannot use distance in Euclidean space, so all differences *θ − θ<sub>i</sub>* should be replaced by considering the angle between two vectors:
>
> $d_i\theta)= \| \theta -\theta_i \| = \min(|\theta-\theta_i|, 2π -|\theta-\theta_i|).$

-- Charles C Taylor. Automatic bandwidth selection for circular density estimation. *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*
Volume 52, Issue 7, 15 March 2008, Pages 3493-3500. doi: [10.1016/j.csda.2007.11.003](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2007.11.003)

He references these books:

S. Rao Jammalamadaka and A. SenGupta, *Topics in Circular Statistics*, World Scientific, Singapore (2001).

K.V. Mardia and P.E. Jupp, *Directional Statistics*, John Wiley, Chichester (1999).